# Change mouse cursor image in application?

Tags: android, mouse

I able to connected mouse with my device and it's working perfectly, but I want to change cursor image for specific to app. How we can do it. Any idea/suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible on a per-app basis. The pointer icon images are part of the framework and their style attributes are internal.

From `core/res/res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<!-- Pointer styles -->
<style name="Pointer">
    <item name="android:pointerIconArrow">@android:drawable/pointer_arrow_icon</item>
    <item name="android:pointerIconSpotHover">@android:drawable/pointer_spot_hover_icon</item>
    <item name="android:pointerIconSpotTouch">@android:drawable/pointer_spot_touch_icon</item>
    <item name="android:pointerIconSpotAnchor">@android:drawable/pointer_spot_anchor_icon</item>
</style>
```

And from `core/res/res/values/themes.xml`:

```
<!-- Pointer style -->
<item name="pointerStyle">@android:style/Pointer</item>
```

Since they are internal, you won't be able to override them in your own styles.

Comment: yes that's true I think, but I think some hacky way to do same..
http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/android-overlay-cursor/#.UmjDQpAW0kc

Comment: Interesting approach. But since the device manufacturer could replace the images you would need to supply an overlay big enough to cover it in every situation or it would look strange. Also, from a user's perspective I'd dislike an app doing this.

Comment: Yes, it make app more complex, and since it's using overlay here so same create problem for other app as well.