# Customizing color of default cursor mover in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, apk

In addition to cursor which is like a short line, there is another thing that when user click on the edittext appears and by moving that cursor will move to edit a text . I donot know what is its name (Im not native in English) so I cant customize its color .This is blue for google chrome for instance and by this thing you can pass through every character of text. Can anyone help me with this element of edittext please ? Tnx in advance .[image]

Comment: by default your cursor color is  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> change the accent color will change the cursor color. you can also use that in editext android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"

Comment: but what I want to change is not the cursor . you know, it's a kind of cursor position changer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize that pointer from your style:

```
<style name="CustomEditTextView" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/your_prefer_color</item>       
</style>
```

Include this style in `EditText`:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomEditTextView"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can create a shape drawable named drawable_cursor_white ( for white cursor ) as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Thereafter, just use attribute textCursorDrawable as follows in the EditText as follows :

```
<EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/drawable_cursor_white" />
```

Or else, if you want to apply the custom cursor everywhere in your application, then you can create a theme and apply it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Above both the answer is correct if you want to change the color of the cursor

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
android:textColor="Color"
```

you can also do that using the java

```
Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(yourEditText, R.drawable.cursor);
```

But if you want to change the position as you mention in comment use that

```
editText.setSelection(position)
```

Change the color of the pointer

In your styles.xml put like this:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
```

Some link you may refer  [Change mouse cursor image in application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558849/change-mouse-cursor-image-in-application)

you may also refer that http://www.pocketmagic.net/android-overlay-cursor/#.UmjDQpAW0kc

Comment: tnx . there is a thing that is bigger than cursor and is like a triangle with circular corners that when user click on the text it appears suddenly to help the user change the position of the cursor in order to edit the text but unfortunstely I donot know its name and I know its color is capabale of customizing .

Comment: @PedramYazdipour you can add the screenshot at the question

Comment: can u please give me your email address if u dont mind because stackoverflow doesnot let me send images . I donot have 10 reputation .

Comment: @PedramYazdipour i update the answer plz check that may be that help you

Comment: tnx a lot . sorry for my mistakes.